# how to set an alarm 5 mins before an event?

Tags: java, android, alert, alarm

I m creating a APP that works like a virtual time card: The user enter what time he enters at work, what time he goes out for lunch and what time he comes back at work again. Then he presses a button and he can see what time he can go out. Of course this is useful for whom, like me, have a flexible working hour.

The APP works. Now I'd like to add a new feature. Let's say I can exit my office at 5 PM, I'd like that my APP at 16:55 sent me a notification, an alarm. Something that reminds me that I can go out. How can do it ?

In my mind I have these steps:

1. I put in a variable the time I can go out from work
2. I check the current time and if it's five mins before the point 1 sends a notification

But, the program has to do this check everytime or once each minute at least. And I really don't know how to do it..

Can anyone helpe me out with an idea?

Ivano

- Edit according to the rules and my new updates  -

sorry my delay but I had to study what you sent me because I am a super rookie in Java... And i am really struggling trying to learn new things... Anyway let's get to the point. I tried to use the AlarmManager but It's not doing what I would like.

I added this code at the top of my MainActivity class:

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OnAlarmReceive.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,  intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),1*60*1000, pendingIntent);
```

What I get is that each 60 seconds the APP reloads itself, calls the MainActivity class and reloads the values the user entered previously into the DB. Therefore there is no way to enter a new value without see!!

What Id like is: The app stays in background "forever" and wakes itself up only when realises that in 5 minutes the user can leave the office.

I already wrote the part of the code where the program checks the current time and ask itself "does it lack 5 mins before the user can leave the office ? " and if the answer is yes, a text message appears and a sound is played. This is the part of the code :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder n  = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Arrivato nuovo messaggio!!")
                .setContentText("Autore: Nicola Rossi")
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(sound);
```

So, the program works.. but has a minor glitch, where it only sends the notification out when I open the app 5-minutes before the end of my shift. If I open the app at any other time, it will not send out the notification. I want this notification to be sent out regardless of the time I open the app.

How can I fix it?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called an alarm manager. This is a service outside your app you can use to notify the user. This service is called upon using pending intents.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check if your minute var is > 4. If it is simply check if current local hour matches your hour var and your local minute = varMinute-5. Next, if your varMinute variable is less than 5 you need a series of if statements where you manually change the hour to (hour-1) and the min var to 59 if your minute var is 4, 58 if it is 3 so on and so forth down to 0 and 55.

You also need a send variable that gets checked to see if you have already sent an alert that minute and reset it every time seconds=0

This is in mql4 and uses an array (to set as many alarms as you want) but you get the point. alertSend needs to be global

```
      void MyAlarm()
      {  
        int localDay = TimeDay(TimeLocal());
        int localHour = TimeHour(TimeLocal());
        int localMinute = TimeMinute(TimeLocal());
        int alertHour=0;
        int alertMinute=0;
        
      for(int i=0; i<ArraySize(array1); i++) 
      {         
         if(array4[i]>4)
         {
           alertHour=array3[i];
           alertMinute=array4[i]-5;      
         }
         if(array4[i]==4)
         {
           alertHour=array3[i]-1;
           alertMinute=59;     
         }
         if(array4[i]==3)
         {
           alertHour=array3[i]-1;
           alertMinute=58;     
         }
         if(array4[i]==2)
         {
           alertHour=array3[i]-1;
           alertMinute=57;     
         }
         if(array4[i]==1)
         {
           alertHour=array3[i]-1;
           alertMinute=56;     
         }
         if(array4[i]==0)
         {
           alertHour=array3[i]-1;
           alertMinute=55;     
         } 
         if(localDay==array2[i] && localHour==alertHour && localMinute==alertMinute && alertSend)
         {    
             Alert("Close trades for ",array1[i]);
             alertSend=false;
         }                                         
     }
                    
       if(Seconds()==0)
       {
         alertSend=true;
       }
          
  }
```